# Couchdb locking documents on bulk update

Tags: couchdb

Is there a way to create locks in Couchdb while performing bulk save? I believe there is no inbuilt method to achieve this, but would it be possible to solve this with a workaround? I have a scenario similar to following (I use Node.js to interact with couchdb database):

User pays another user creating a new document object as follows:

```
{
    _id: SOMEID
    type: "PAYMENT"
    username: SOMEUSER
    paidto: ANOTHERUSER
    amount: 10
}
```

When this is saved I also need to update remaining balance the user has in his/her `account document` (subtract 10 from his/her wallet). Then I save both of these documents at once with bulk_docs (newly created `transaction document` and the updated `account document`).

But if during this process the user makes changes to the `account document` through some other method (let's say in another tab) we have an issue where the new `transaction document` is saved while the `account document` cannot be updated. This creates a big issue and consistency problem.

To solve this we will have to lock `account document` until the bulk save process ends, during which process in second tab waits for the lock to be released.

I am trying to deploy Couchdb is an environment where consistency between documents is quite important but without locks, this is turning out to be very difficult.

Answer (score 1):

> When this is saved I also need to update remaining balance the user has in his/her account document (subtract 10 from his/her wallet).

Don't. Banking is a [very well documented example](http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/recipes.html#banking) for document databases. Best practices is to store only transactions as documents, and consider account balance as a query to a view (of transactions indexed by accounts).

## Map

```
function(o) {
  if (o.paidto && o.amount && o.username) {
    emit(o.paidto, o.amount);
    emit(o.username, -o.amount);
  }
}
```

## Reduce

```
_sum
```

## Query

```
GET /mydb/_design/mydesign/_view/myview/?group=true&key=SOMEUSER
```

Comment: Yes but how will you solve race conditions? Let's say you cannot spend more than you have i.e. total cannot be negative. Currently you have 20$ in your wallet. Now let's say two "spending" processes start at the same time each drawing 20$. They will check how much they have in the wallet and then initiate spend. If the second process checks and completes a transaction while the first one has just checked and is about to complete a transaction, the first one could cause the wallet to go to negative -20$?

Comment: @pewpewlasers Good question. My first thought would be to mimic how it is probably done in a bank: the transaction was created, but then an invalidation order was sent. You can do that for example with a [NodeJS process listening to `_changes ` API](https://github.com/iriscouch/follow), requesting the view to get the account balance of the corresponding user, and sending an invalidation order (a special document) if it is over the overdraft limit.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I will try your method out.